# Is any way to add the changes to undo/redo stack made by Excel addin?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Here I am using Office.js API in Excel add-in. When I export any table or information using Excel add-in, the undo and redo buttons are disabled, and the undo/redo stack is cleared.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for reporting this question.
Excel currently clears its undo stack after add-in operations. We’re looking at ways to support this in the future for the JavaScript APIs only in a way that will require almost no change on your part, but it will take some time to add that support such that we can light it up (we want to make sure all APIs are covered before lighting up add-in undo). BTW, as the add-in action may trigger save/auto-save, it’s not a trivial work to keep a reliable undo stack without the add-in actions.